# How can I disable shortcuts from being created after install from Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-2, home-screen-shortcuts

I own a Galaxy S2 with the Samsung ICS stock, and I've noticed when I download an application from Google Play (Market) it installs it and automatically places the app shortcut on the first free space it finds on the launcher front.

Is there any way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the Play Store, go into its settings, and uncheck the 'Auto-add widgets' option. The option also applies to shortcut auto-creation (which makes the name rather misleading).

Comment: thanks, didn't knew shortcuts were technically considered widgets

Comment: @svarog: I think the name of that option is just misleading for some reason, although I suppose it's possible that they are considered "widgets" by the system. I actually don't know if they're technically widgets or not.