# Is there anyway I can disable the posting of app shortcuts on my home-screen when an app is installed?

Tags: applications, home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable shortcuts from being created after install from Google Play?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24398/how-can-i-disable-shortcuts-from-being-created-after-install-from-google-play)

Every time I install an app a shortcut gets created on my home-screen, I don't want this to happen so I am wondering if there is a way to prevent the creation of shortcuts unless I want them created.

Comment: If you are not talking about Google Play then please edit this to clarify (however, I do not know of any other installation method that auto-creates shortcuts like Google Play does).